# Facet_grid labeller repeating level for all labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am trying to label the rows on my grid using `label_bquote`.

Here is what I have so far:`labeller = label_bquote(rows=mu=="1x10"^.(levels(Mut_Rate))`

The levels of Mut_Rate are: `levels(all_summ$Mut_Rate)<-c("-4","-5","-6","-7","-8")`

When I run the labeller I get the following labels for my rows:

[[image]]

Why is this? I would like the labels to be mu=1x10^-4,-5,-6,etc.

I am all for another way to do this but I have this working for other plots and I don't know why this isn't working.

Using the `mpg` data set I can recreate the issue (somewhat).

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
levels(mpg$drv)<-c("4","f","r",)
p + facet_grid(drv ~ cyl,labeller = label_bquote(rows=mu=="1x10" ^ .(levels(drv))))
```

Results in: [image]

Where am I going wrong?

Edit: Here is `dput` for a subset of my data:

```
structure(list(Mut_Rate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1e-08", "1e-07", 
"1e-06", "1e-05", "1e-04"), class = "factor"), colors_here = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("100", 
"500", "1000", "5000", "10000"), class = "factor"), x_values = c(1, 
100, 2600, 28, 1450, 29, 1500, 6, 350, 2850, 33, 1700, 10, 550, 
3050, 37, 1900, 14, 750, 6100, 41, 2100, 18, 950, 10100, 45, 
2300, 22, 1150, 14100, 49, 2500, 26, 1350, 3, 200, 2700, 30, 
1550, 7, 400, 2900, 34, 1750, 11, 600, 3100, 38, 1950, 15, 800, 
7100, 42, 2150, 19, 1000, 11100, 46, 2350, 23, 1200, 15100, 49, 
2500, 25, 1300, 1, 100, 2600, 27, 1400, 3, 200, 2700, 29, 1500, 
5, 300, 2800, 31, 1600, 7, 400, 2900, 33, 1700, 9, 500, 3000, 
35, 1800, 11, 600, 3100, 37, 1900, 13, 700, 5100, 39, 2000, 15, 
800, 7100, 41, 2100, 17, 900, 9100, 43, 2200), y_values = c(0, 
1.518e-06, 3.001e-06, 1.32e-07, 8.16e-06, 4.87e-07, 5.771e-06, 
0, 3.086e-06, 2.5878e-05, 2.31e-07, 1.3455e-05, 0, 7.96875e-05, 
3.09375e-06, 0, 9.746875e-05, 0, 0.00013453125, 0.00039434375, 
6.1875e-06, 0.00017896875, 0, 0.000115, 0.0005994375, 6.68125e-05, 
7.14375e-05, 1.2375e-05, 0.00071890625, 0.0008070625, 3.94375e-05, 
0.0011611875, 1.95625e-05, 0.0011889375, 0, 0.00019146875, 0.002583875, 
0.00018528125, 0.00210109375, 4.303125e-05, 0.003006375, 0.0080869375, 
0.00034940625, 0.01132409375, 6.05e-05, 0.00564815625, 0.025672, 
0.0003765, 0.01874928125, 0.00113753125, 0.0190550625, 0.016886125, 
0.0040905, 0.07532540625, 0.00186221875, 0.07132434375, 0.14220003125, 
0.00397665625, 0.16759309375, 0.0017900625, 0.10347159375, 0.39214809375, 
1.111e-06, 7.506e-06, 3.307e-06, 1.8439e-05, 1.72e-06, 2.63e-06, 
2.733e-05, 2.97e-07, 1.1348e-05, 1.621e-05, 4.4035e-05, 0.000104525, 
1.084e-05, 0.0001369, 3.2165e-05, 6.376e-05, 0.000254345, 2.3765e-05, 
0.00012591, 0.000294945, 0.000551865, 0.001035845, 0.000170355, 
0.001156965, 0.00021164, 0.000689675, 0.002610485, 0.00026225, 
0.002045535, 0.0021557, 0.0054404, 0.00898055, 0.0018754, 0.01137135, 
0.00241075, 0.00888815, 0.04158005, 0.00230105, 0.0195085, 0.020169, 
0.0575235, 0.0791955, 0.0199717, 0.1158792, 0.01812125, 0.09193755, 
0.32251755, 0.02459615, 0.18119415), columns_here = c(2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)), .Names = c("Mut_Rate", 
"colors_here", "x_values", "y_values", "columns_here"), row.names = c(1L, 
51L, 101L, 151L, 201L, 251L, 301L, 351L, 401L, 451L, 501L, 551L, 
601L, 651L, 701L, 751L, 801L, 851L, 901L, 951L, 1001L, 1051L, 
1101L, 1151L, 1201L, 1251L, 1301L, 1351L, 1401L, 1451L, 1501L, 
1551L, 1601L, 1651L, 1701L, 1751L, 1801L, 1851L, 1901L, 1951L, 
2001L, 2051L, 2101L, 2151L, 2201L, 2251L, 2301L, 2351L, 2401L, 
2451L, 2501L, 2551L, 2601L, 2651L, 2701L, 2751L, 2801L, 2851L, 
2901L, 2951L, 3001L, 3051L, 3101L, 3151L, 3201L, 3251L, 3301L, 
3351L, 3401L, 3451L, 3501L, 3551L, 3601L, 3651L, 3701L, 3751L, 
3801L, 3851L, 3901L, 3951L, 4001L, 4051L, 4101L, 4151L, 4201L, 
4251L, 4301L, 4351L, 4401L, 4451L, 4501L, 4551L, 4601L, 4651L, 
4701L, 4751L, 4801L, 4851L, 4901L, 4951L, 5001L, 5051L, 5101L, 
5151L, 5201L, 5251L, 5301L, 5351L, 5401L, 5451L, 5501L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code that I am running to make the plot:

```
    q<-ggplot(for_stack,aes(x=x_values, y=y_values,color=colors_here))+
      geom_point(data=for_stack,size=4)+
      theme(text = element_text(size=18),legend.position = "bottom",strip.background = element_blank())

    q+facet_grid(Mut_Rate~columns_here, scales="free_y", as.table = FALSE,labeller=label_bquote(rows = .(Mut_Rate),cols=N[e0]==.(columns_here)))+
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"),legend.key=element_blank())#The numbers look OK but no mu=

q<-ggplot(for_stack,aes(x=x_values, y=y_values,color=colors_here))+
  geom_point(data=for_stack,size=4)+
  theme(text = element_text(size=18),legend.position = "bottom",strip.background = element_blank())

q+facet_grid(Mut_Rate~columns_here, scales="free_y", as.table = FALSE,labeller=label_bquote(rows = mu== "1x10"^ .(Mut_Rate),cols=N[e0]==.(columns_here)))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"),legend.key=element_blank())#Looks great but the superscript numbers are incorrect. I need mu=1x10^-4, mu=1x10^-5, etc.
```

The levels are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hard to say why, but it's `levels` what causes the problem. Instead using

```
label_bquote(rows = mu == "1x10" ^ .(drv))
```

does the job.

---

**Edit**: the issue is that `Mut_Rate` is a factor. Explicitly making sure that it's numeric fixes the issue. In the first case you could use

```
mu == .(as.numeric(as.character(Mut_Rate)))
```

but that's not the desired format, I presume. In the second case we can have

```
mu== "1x10"^ .(log10(as.numeric(as.character(Mut_Rate))))
```

which looks as intended, I believe.

Comment: This works for the mpg plot but unfortunately not for my data which is the strangest part.

I have narrowed down the culprit to adding anything besides `rows = .(Mut_Rate)`
If I add `mu ==.(Mut_Rate)` or ` "1x10" ^.(Mut_Rate) ` then I get the rows being labeled as mu=1, mu=2,etc or 1x10^1,1x10^2, etc.

Comment: @AMB, perhaps you could reproduce your issue with `dput`?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not heard of `dput`, Would wrapping my ggplot+facet_grid object work?

Comment: @AMB, I have in mind sharing (part of) your data, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, and then some code, as to fully reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AMB, didn't see that you updated your question. See the update.